# Strange bootstrap behavior with button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC application, with controller actions:

```
 public class InviteUserController : BaseController
 {
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
        return View();
     }

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Index(InviteUserDetailsViewModel inviteUserDetails)
     {
     }
 }
```

And in the view:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "InviteUser", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
 {
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Versturen</button>  
 }
```

If I click the button, the controller action method Index (POST) is hit correctly.

But, if I change the button to hide the button text on small screens:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> <span class="hidden-xs">Versturen</span></button>
```

...then if I click it, nothing happens. The controller action method is not called.

Any idea why this is happening? Alternatives to hide the button text on small screens?

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS `:after` and `content: ""` as a work-around - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/9aoks98h/1/)

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
    <i id="versturen" class="fa fa-check"></i>
</button> 

#versturen:after {
    content: " Versturen";
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #versturen:after {
    content: "";
  }
}
```

Although keep in mind that this is not screen reader friendly... I guess you could add `<span class="sr-only">Versturen</span>` into the button to fix that.

I guess another route would be to highjack the `.sr-only` class and add a media-query to it - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/0ccb0z6m/)

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
    <i id="versturen" class="fa fa-check"></i>
    <span class="sr-only-xs"> Versturen</span>
</button>

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .sr-only-xs {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    border: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. But is this a bug, or expected behavior?

Comment: @L-Three I'm really not sure what the root cause of the issue is, but I would assume it has something to do with the `.hidden-xs` adding `display: none` to the button's child element... so here are some work-arounds that don't involve `display: none`